# Fill in zeros for variable in pandas dataframe without group by values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

| column1 | sum_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |

However, there are 5 values in column1  (1-5). I would like to fill in 0s for values that do not have a sum_count like this:

| column1 | sum_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can use the `.reindex` facility but "column1" needs to go to index and come back:

```py
In [154]: (df.set_index("column1")
     ...:    .reindex(range(1, 5 + 1), fill_value=0)
     ...:    .reset_index())
Out[154]:
   column1  sum_count
0        1         10
1        2          0
2        3          2
3        4          0
4        5          1
```

for dynamism in 1 and 5:

- 1 is `df.column1.iat[0]`, 5 is `df.column1.iat[-1]` OR
- `df.column1.iloc[[0, -1]]` to get both with one expr OR
- 1 is `df.column1.min()`,  5 is `df.column1.max()`